# DCHP with database backend

Tags: database, dhcp

Here my first question :P.

I am developing some little projectes. I want to change dhcp server rules of IP/MAC without rebooting the server (In a dinamic infrastructure).

I think that the best solution is to use a dhcp server with a database backend, in order to change the SQL information (With an easy JDBC client).

But I want to know some suggestion about open Source Projects, or howto's that explain how to implement it.

Thank you very much

Comment: more information please. windows or unix? why do you think the server needs to be rebooted between changes?

Comment: SpliFF

On Unix.

No, restart the DHCP server, no the machine :). Sorry.

Because when you change the dhcp.conf you need to restart the dhcp (dhcpd)

Comment: This seems to belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Usually on Unix, long running daemons listen for the HUP signal. On receiving that signal, they re-read their configuration files. This allows daemons to have no down time, but get updated configuration options.

Comment: But If you think in a infraestructure with HUNDREAD of servers, I think (Maybe is a mistake) that it's better to have a database instead of a dhcp config file. Rememeber, only pairs IP/MAC not IP ranges
Thank you

Comment: When you say hundreds of servers, do you mean that to be hundreds of DHCP clients or hundreds of DHCP servers? Also, are you planning on writing a DHCP server from scratch or add a DB backend to an existing program?

Comment: From ISC dhcpd manpage: `We realize that it would be nice if one could send a SIGHUP to the server and have it reload the database.  This is not technically impossible, but it would require a great deal of work, our resources are extremely limited, and they can be better spent elsewhere.`

Old question, old answers but still worth to point out to not lead anyone else down the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

The guys at [ISC](http://www.isc.org/) (authors of BIND and the ISC DHCP server) are working on [KEA](http://kea.isc.org/), a new DHCP server implementation that -- among other nice features -- has SQL support. The source code has had support for SQLite and MySQL for years, and [PostgreSQL](http://kea.isc.org/ticket/3080) support was added recently.

There's no proper release yet, and very little activity on their [dev](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/kea-dev/)/[users](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/kea-users/) mailing lists. Hopefully that will change as the code matures, releases are made, distros start packaging it, and it gains traction with users.

Answer (score -1):

SpliFF

On Unix.

No, restart the DHCP server, no the machine :). Sorry.

Because when you change the dhcp.conf you need to restart the dhcp (dhcpd)